# How do you let a Java applet write into your temp folder? (Windows)

Tags: windows-7, java, java-applet

There is an old Java applet that works with XP. But if you open it up from Windows 7 and from any Java plugin, it won't work. The plugin itself would export some data... as an excel sheet. The applet gets downloaded, but there is an IOException.

Here is the debug log:

```
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
/tmp/dixtemp1234.dat
C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Temp\\001.TXT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://domain/cgi-bin/viewLog.cgi?pg=5&UID=001&StartTime=1348153140&EndTime=1348239540&SampleTime=900&ID=2368%7C3368%7C12368%7C13368%7C19368%7C20368%7C, version: null]
network: Connecting http://domain/cgi-bin/viewLog.cgi?pg=5&UID=001&StartTime=1348153140&EndTime=1348239540&SampleTime=900&ID=2368%7C3368%7C12368%7C13368%7C19368%7C20368%7C with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://domain/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://domain/cgi-bin/viewLog.cgi?pg=5&UID=001&StartTime=1348153140&EndTime=1348239540&SampleTime=900&ID=2368%7C3368%7C12368%7C13368%7C19368%7C20368%7C with cookie "user=Admin"
Exception in comm thread: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \tmp\temp1234.dat (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I have found some links...
http://doc.sumy.ua/prog/java/javanut/ch16_01.htm
This page says I have to use a "properties" file. But I can't make a `.hotjava` folder, as it's not possible to do so on NTFS. I've tried to save the xls file into my temp folder, or under Public, and so on. But it doesn't work.

The error I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsxgQ.jpg

Ps.: A single user will use this thing, so I can't just use a VM with XP installed. Ty.

Comment: Why can't you create a `.hotjava` directory in an NTFS file system on Windows 7?  I just did?  Also `git` and other utilities do?

Comment: You are right about the other apps, but for me it doesn't work. I'll try it from command line. (See edit, for what happens.)

Comment: yeah, mkdir .hotjava works. lemme check.

Comment: Yes, I created mine from the command line `mkdir .hotjava`, you uncovered a Windows GUI issue ...

Comment: same error, IOException, file not found. Again: This works in XP. (But I'll give it a reboot.. that's just magical on Windows.)

Comment: Is your temp directory `\tmp` or `c:\users\x\temp`?  Could there be some confusion there?  Check all of your environment variables, maybe a couple are out of sync.

Comment: The applet is not working on any Windows 7 PCs. The only place where it worked was a machine running XP. :/ I was thinking if there is a way to give it uber-super-rights to let it do anything. I even added the site to IE's secure list, but that didn't help either. Maybe some Java VM command switch?

Comment: Did you try running the applet from a command prompt that was started using `run as administrator`?  I've seen Vista and Win7 prevent non-administrator processes from creating directories in the root of the c-drive.  However, if `\tmp` already exists then creating a file in `\tmp` shouldn't be an issue.  I also am troubled that the reference to `\tmp` doesn't include the drive letter.  That could be an issue between operating system versions.  i.e. different defaults.

Comment: Damn @HeatfanJohn! And that C:\tmp really works. So simple, yet so retarded. (The problem that is.) Please post that as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing any references you have from `\tmp` to `c:\tmp` or to include the specific drive that you are using.